# Android - Attach a click listener to a RemoteViews

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-remoteview

Suppose I have created an instance of `RemoteViews` and it contains two `Button`s. I want when user clicks these buttons a `Service` (or a `BroadcastReceiver` or something else ) handles this click. As I know so far, there is two ways for achieve this purpose :

1. Assign different Actions to these Buttons for example
   **ACTION_BTN_1_CLICKED**
   and
   **ACTION_BTN_2_CLICKED**
   and then retrieve the action in the Service via `intent.getAction()` and finally service does a appropriate task
2. Put some extra into the Intent object which is enclosed via `PendingIntent` for example:

   `intent.putStringExtra("which_button", "btn1"); // for Button 1`
   and
   `intent.putStringExtra("which_button", "btn2"); // for Button 2`

   In the other hand in Service I can distinguish this signal via `intent.getExtras().getString("which_button")`

Now my question is which approach is better at least in practice? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can argue one being better than another, but I think the second solution might be more manageable and extendable. You could put an `Integer` extra, perhaps IDs that you declare in the `R` class. This ensures that they are unique and allows you to reference them in `switch` statement. It also means your routing code is in one place, so if there is a bug there it will be easier to find.